# How to add onClick event on embed tag?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, embed-tag

I want to add onclick event on embed tag but the problem is,it is not working on chrome and the handler is not working.Other than onclick event mouseover and mouseleave are working.here is the code
***HTML***

```
<embed src="http://localhost/credit-app1/" onclick="increaseSize()" onload="bottomRight()">
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function increaseSize(){
    var embedtag = document.querySelector("embed");
    if(embedtag.style.width == "400px"){
        embedtag.style.width = "100px";
        embedtag.style.height = "100px";
    }else{
        embedtag.style.width = "400px";
        embedtag.style.height = "500px"; 
    }
    console.log(embedtag)
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are clicking the content of the `embed` which does not have your click event.

Comment: @Lain the code works when you give it to wrapper div but not excatly perfect. I wonder what can we do as workaround for this problem.

Comment: I just changed the src of embed tag to src="https://img.icons8.com/color/40/000000/mastercard.png"  it works perfectly fine but when I am giving the src="http://localhost/credit-app1/" of my app it is not working I wonder why @Erenn

Answer (score 0):

you could just do it with pure css using the hover effect:

```
embed:hover {
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

Im not sure how it should work with `onclick()`, because the content inside will never have the click Event...

**OR:**

You could try to lay a transparent `<div>` over the embeded content:

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0; background-color: transparent;" onclick="increaseSize()"></div>
<embed src="http://localhost/credit-app1/" onload="bottomRight()" style="position: relative;">
```

in the JavaScript you need too resize the div too.